# Why is this integral zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

I was solving a problem on Fourier Analysis ( namely, I was proving that $\int|f|^2dx=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |f(n)|^2$ if $f$ is of moderate decrease and the fourier transform of $f$ is supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$) and the problem boils down to proving that this integral is zero for $n\not=m$ where $n$ and $m$  are both integers:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x-n)}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x-m)}dx=0$$

I am not really sure how to compute this integral. I know $\sin(\pi x)^2/x^2$ can be integrated using the fourier transform of a characteristic function. I tried to adapt this here but to no avail.

Comment: Silly me. The integrand is symetric with respect to $\frac{n+m}{2}$. Sorry, I should have thought a little harder before asking.

Comment: Hint: The integrand can be formulated as the product of two $\mathrm{sinc}(\cdot)$ functions and is symmetric about $\frac{m}{2} + \frac{n}{2}$. Edit: Ah, just saw your comment.

Comment: I could be missing something, but I don't see how it being the product of two sinc functions symmetrical about some point immplies that the integral is 0.

The most natural way (to me) would be to use partial fractions on the denominator to split it into a sum of two odd functions offset from the origin.

Comment: @Polygon, break the integral in $\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{n+m}{2}}+\int_{\frac{n+m}{2}}^{\infty}$ and then use $x=\frac{n+m}{2}-y$ for the first one and $x=\frac{n+m}{2}+y$ for the second one. Feel free to post your answer with partial fractions though... :)

Comment: The partial fraction way ended up not being quite as simple as I thought -- it turns out neither integral converges on its own, but we can still show that their difference does converge to $0$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f_{k}(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\left [-{1\over 2},{1\over 2}\right ]}e^{2\pi i kx}$ is square integrable
and its Fourier transform is equal
$$\widehat{f_k}(t)={1\over \pi  (k-t)}\sin\pi (k-t)=(-1)^k{\sin\pi  t\over \pi(t-k)}$$
By the Plancherel identity
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\overline{f_m(x)}\,dx =\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f_n}(t)\overline{\widehat{f_m}(t)}\,dt\\ ={(-1)^{n+m}\over \pi^2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{\sin\pi t\over t-m}{\sin \pi t\over t-n}\,dt$$
The left hand side integral vanishes for $n\neq m,$ as the functions $ e^{2\pi i mx}$ and  $ e^{2\pi i nx}$ are orthogonal in $L^2\left (-{1\over 2},{1\over 2}\right )$ for $m\neq n.$ This gives the conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

We can use partial fractions to break up the denominator:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(x-n\right)\left(x-m\right)} = \frac{1}{n-m}\left(\frac{1}{x-n}-\frac{1}{x-m}\right).
$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x-n)}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x-m)}dx &= \frac1{n-m} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x - n} - \frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x - m}\right)dx \\
&= \lim_{a,b \to \infty} \frac1{n-m} \left(\int_{-a}^b \frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x - n}dx - \int_{-a}^b\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x - m}dx\right).
\end{align}
For the first integral, let $u = x + n$, and for the second, let $u = x + m$. Noting that in both cases $sin^2(\pi x) = sin^2(\pi u)$, we get
$$
\lim_{a,b \to \infty} \frac1{n-m} \left(\int_{-a - n}^{b - n} \frac{\sin^2(\pi u)}udu - \int_{-a - m}^{b - m}\frac{\sin^2(\pi u)}udu\right)
$$

Omitting the insides of the integrals to save space, we can break up the integrals like this:
$$
\int_{-a - n}^{b - n} - \int_{-a - m}^{b - m}   =   \left[\int_{-a - n}^{-a - m} + \int_{-a - m}^{b - n}\right] - \left[\int_{-a - m}^{b - n} + \int_{b - n}^{b - m}\right]   =   \int_{-a - n}^{-a - m} - \int_{b - n}^{b - m}.
$$
This leaves us with
$$
\lim_{a,b \to \infty} \frac1{n-m} \left(\int_{-a - n}^{-a - m} \frac{\sin^2(\pi u)}udu - \int_{b - n}^{b - m}\frac{\sin^2(\pi u)}udu\right),
$$
and both integrals clearly converge to $0$ as $a$ and $b$ increase.

---

To justify the claim that the integrals "clearly" converge to $0$, I will prove it for the second integral. Without loss of generality, assume that $n > m$. Then, if $b > n$,

\begin{align}
0 < \int_{b - n}^{b - m}\frac{\sin^2(\pi u)}udu &\leq \int_{b - n}^{b - m}\frac1udu \\
&\leq \int_{b - n}^{b - m}\frac1{b - n}du \\
&= \frac{n - m}{b - n}.
\end{align}
As $b \to \infty$, $\frac{n-m}{b-n} \to 0$, which proves that the second integral converges to $0$. A symmetrical argument applies to the first integral.

Comment: Why should each integral converge to $0$ as $a\rightarrow\infty$. $t\mapsto\frac{\sin^2\pi t}{t}$ not in $L_1$ and so, the tails may not converge to 40$.

Comment: @Mittens in the last formula, we aren't integrating over the entire real line. We're integrating over two regions of fixed length $|n - m|$. As $a, b \to \infty$, these regions move further and further from the origin, so $\frac{\sin^2 \pi t}t$ becomes arbitrarily small in them.

Comment: I understand that you have something of the form $\int_{I_n(a)}f(x)$ where $\int_n(a)$ in an finite interval that increases with $a$, but unless this does not imply, in general, that $\int_{I_n(a)}-\int_{I_m(a)} f$ becomes small. Some additional arguments are needed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your objection, but I added a justification that the second integral converges to $0$, which should be easy to apply to the first integral as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suffices to consider
$$I=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x(x-k)}\,dx=(-1)^k\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin\pi x}{x}\frac{\sin\pi(x-k)}{x-k}\,dx$$
for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that
$$\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]})(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i2\pi xt}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x)\,dx=\frac{\sin  \pi t}{ \pi t}$$
and
$$
\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]})(t-k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i2\pi x(t-k)}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x)\,dx=\frac{\sin \pi(t-k)}{\pi(t-k)}=\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi ixk}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]})(t)
$$

Since the Fourier transform is self-adjoint

\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^2}I&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi t}\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi ixk}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]})(t)\,dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathcal{F}\Big(\frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi t}\Big)(x) e^{2i\pi xk}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x)\,dx\\
&=\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}e^{2\pi ixk}\,dx=\frac{e^{\pi ik}-e^{-\pi i k}}{2\pi i k}=\frac{\sin \pi k}{\pi k}=0
\end{align}
since $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

A more direct proof can be obtained without the use of Fourier analysis. Notice that $g:x\mapsto\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}$ is odd and locally integrable; furthermore, $x\mapsto g(x)g(x-k)$ is integrable. Then, for $a>0$ large enough
\begin{align}
I_a&=\int^a_{-a}\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x(x-k)}\,dx=\frac{1}{k}\int^a_{-a}\Big(\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}-\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x-k}\Big)\,dx\\
&=-\frac1k\int^{a-k}_{-a-k}\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}\,dx=-\frac1k\Big(\int^{-a+k}_{-a-k}+\int^{a-k}_{-a+k}\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}\,dx\Big)\\
&=-\frac1k\int^{-a+k}_{-a-k}\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}\,dx
\end{align}
finally, observe that
$$\Big|\int^{-a+k}_{-a-k}\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{x}\,dx\Big|\leq \int^{a+k}_{a-k}\frac{dx}{x}=\log\big(\frac{a+k}{a-k}\big)\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow\infty}0$$
The conclusion follows by dominated convergence.

Comment: I have one question. Why is it that we may use self-adjointness if one of the functions is not of moderate decrease?

Comment: The functions involved are in $L_2$. The Fourier transform is selfadjoni on $L_2$, tha is du  ehe whole Plancherel theory.

Answer (score 0):

I used $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} {f}(n)\frac{\sin(\pi(x-n))}{\pi(x-n)}$ and expanded $|f(x)|^2$ using the fact this series is commutatively convergent to yield the expression. But this results in some cumbersome integrals and it is a bit tedious to prove our relation this way.  Of course this initial approach also yields the right answer, but it ocurred to me there is a more natural way to do this!

---

By Plancharel and also using that $\hat{f}$ has compact support in $[-1/2,1/2]$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(w)|^2dw=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|\hat{f}(w)|^2$$

We may view the restriction of $\hat{f}$ as a continuous function on the circle. In this case, we have that is integrable in the circle and by Parseval we have:

$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|\hat{f}(w)|^2dw=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|a_n|^2 $$

Where $a_n$ is given by:

$$a_n=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\hat{f}(w)e^{-2\pi i n w}dw=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(w)e^{2\pi i (-n) w}dw={f}(-n)$$

Here we have used the Inversion Formula ($f$ and $\hat{f}$ are of moderate decrease). Substituting this expression in the equalities above yields:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2dx=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|{f}(n)|^2$$